# godot key tap and key hold how to?

Tags: input, gdscript, godot4

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
    jump_timer += delta
    current_speed = crouchspeed
    
elif Input.is_action_just_released("jump") and is_on_floor():
    animation_player.play("headbob when jumping")
    if jump_timer >= 1:
        velocity.y = jump_velocity
    elif jump_timer <= 1:
        velocity.y = wall_jump_velocity
```

this is my new script and here i was trying have to player jump higher when the key is held for more than a second, i tried doing this with a timer but it seems like i dont know how to make one.

Comment: How does the behavior you got differ from what you wanted?

Comment: idk what you mean by that but what i meant to have is when i hold down the button the character jumps higher while if i tap it it just normal jumps. but now if i hold it down it down it normal jumps than highjumps, but even if i tap it it counts it as a highjump too

Comment: Sounds like you probably need to store the time. This is the doubt I have right now: do you want the character to jump on press (this is what most platformers do), or do you want the character to jump or release (like a charged jump)?

Comment: To clarify this is the gist of what most platformers do: The instant you press the character jumps, but as long as it is held pressed the character experiences less gravity allowing it jump higher, on release it gets the normal gravity. As a result, holding jump for longer results in jumping higher (more time with the reduced gravity), which matches what you describe. However, I see `crouchspeed` in your code, which makes me think you want the character to load a jump, and jump on release higher or lower depending on how long it was held pressed before release.

Comment: yes i wanted to do a charged jump that happens on release of the key and a normal jump when you just tap the key and while charging for the jump i wanted it to walk slowly and thats why i made it walk in crouchspeed